# What is the term for a 'decoy' feature or intentional bug?

Tags: testing, terminology, debugging, quality, jargon

I have forgotten a slang programming term. This thing is an intentional bug or a decoy feature used as a distraction. An example usage, "Hey Bob, QA is doing a review today. Put a `$THING` into the module so they actually have a problem to find".

This can be used negatively, to have a very obvious intentional flaw to discover as a distraction from a real problem.

This can also be used positively. Its like how you always let rescue dogs 'find' a victim when searching a disaster area. It can also be used to verify that a QA process is actually catching flaws.

What is the term I am looking for?

Comment: obDilbert:  http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2007-02-02/

Comment: I'd like to challenge the close votes. This is an answerable, not-subjective question. It deals with several points from the FAQ: "quality assurance", "developer testing", and "freelancing and business concerns".

Comment: There are similar practices in many fields and it serves a positive purpose: to validate that the process is working. This influences the interpretation of the real results. For example, pregnancy tests. They have two bars that indicate positive result. One result comes from a quality control sample, letting you know whether the device is sensitive to the hCG hormone. [If the quality control bar doesn't appear](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Negative_Pregnancy_Test.JPG), it indicates a problem with the device, invalidating the result.

Comment: Voting to reopen based on this meta discussion: [On the troubles of naming and terminology](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

A Duck

From http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html:

> A feature added for no other reason than to draw management attention and be removed, thus avoiding unnecessary changes in other aspects of the product.

Answer (score 24):

Actually in manufacturing (and quality assurance) there is something called a [Red Rabbit Test](http://thequalityportal.com/glossary/r.htm) (aka Red Herring) that refers to putting a known bad part into the machine or process and making sure it's detected.

> **Red Rabbit Test**
>
> used to check how long it takes to identify a defect. In this test, a red part is added to the mix and the time until it is discovered is identified.

Some automated machines have automatic cycles (typically once per shift) where it prompts the operator to load the "red rabbit" part and then it runs the cycle checking that the error detection and rejection logic work correctly.

Comment: This reminds me of a recent occurrence where an airport was testing its security procedures and did so by placing live explosives in a passenger's luggage. Unfortunately for all involved, it was not detected until the plane had made an (international) stopover -- so I wouldn't necessarily say this is a *good* practice to implement without numerous safeguards.

Answer (score 6):

Seems like my professors called it [bebugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bebugging) or fault seeding.  The idea is that if you wanted to estimate the population of something like fish in a lake, you could catch some, tag and release them, give them time to assimilate randomly with the other fish, then estimate the population based on how many tagged fish you catch later.

[This](http://goo.gl/LZGor) search link finds a page in a book by the late great Watts Humphrey where he talks about this technique.